# git fetch and clone

Tags: git

I have a computer with my git project (computer A). I then did a `git clone` of it to work on it on another computer (computer B). I have made some changes on the new computer (B) and did a `commit` and a `push`. All seems well.

```
$ git push

Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 539 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
To mike@xx.xx.xxx.xx:/photos/
2bf1437..ef7de42  mike -> mike
```

When I go to my original computer (A) and do a `git fetch` it doesn't fetch anything. Is there something I need to do to tell computer B about computer A?

I did a `git pull` on computer B and it says the following:

> Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'mike' from the
>   remote, but no such ref was fetched.

Comment: can you add the command line you are running in B, as well as the output? Your question does not have enough information as it is.

Comment: @mamápitufo - git fetch ... there is no output as if there is nothing to fetch

Comment: Maybe they are in different branches??

Comment: @Kjuly - Well originally there were the same branches and it wouldn't let me push it. I read somewhere that because the other computer had that branch checkout that it wouldn't work. So I created a branch named tmp. I did a push and it pushed just fine and said mike -> mike was sent...as mike I did a fetch and nothing showed up as if I did a push at all

Comment: Run `git remote show origin` on both computers and see what the results are. Specifically, check the remotes are the same and scan for the 'mike' branch in both output. Please post if you don't mind.

Comment: @Christopher +1. or you can use `git remote -v`.

Comment: @Christopher - Looks like computer A is the problem. I remember editing .git/config and trying to have the remote go to a different directory on the same computer. I really didn't understand git at the time. I thought there was one remote repository so I was trying to tell it to look there. I wasn't successful in doing that. Is there a way to reset it? Now on Computer A it is just a local computer...I don't have ssh setup for it so I don't know what I should put in for the remote urls. Any ideas?

Comment: @user98223: it's an easy fix. I posted an answer describing it. Let me know if that fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments on your question, you need to change Computer A's `origin` remote to match B's. On computer B issue the following command:

```
git config remote.origin.url
```

That will output something. Suppose it is `<url>`. Now, on Computer A, issue these commands:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin <url>
```

That removed the bad origin reference and updated it to match B's. Now issue `git push origin mike` from Computer A, and try the fetch again on Computer B. Should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to do `git pull` which does a fetch and a merge.

Comment: When I do a `git pull` it says...Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'mike'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your `remote` set up properly, and then you will need to issue `git pull` which will do the work for you. Actually, `pull` is a combination of `fetch` and `merge` of `FETCH_HEAD` into the current branch.